# Can I receive the newsletter under a different email address?

Tags: feature-request, support, newsletter

I want to subscribe to the newsletter on my work email address but still have everything else go to my normal SO email account. I don't have a way to set up a forwarding filter from my normal email account.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If, while logged in, you subscribe to the stackoverflow.com newsletter, for example, the Stack Overflow newsletter will always be sent to the email address associated with your Stack Overflow account.

However, you can anonymously subscribe to a newsletter using any email address you like:

1. Open an incognito/private/inprivate/pr0n-mode browser window
2. Go to [stackexchange.com/newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters)
3. <strike>???</strike> Subscribe!

The minor drawback of this approach is that your subscription won't be tied to your account, i.e. it won't be listed [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/d755decd-edfa-4e9d-a9bb-ef6c58d9ddd2?tab=subscriptions).

Answer (score -4):

It would be fine to create a second account for this purpose, if you want to track your work email subscriptions using the account features.  Otherwise, as Emmett suggests, log out and subscribe as an anonymous user.  You can still control the subscriptions using the links provided in the newsletters themselves.